# Export mosaic to Google Drive, generating more than just one file and can't download this

Tags: javascript, export, google-earth-engine, mosaic, sentinel-2

I'm exporting a mosaic via google earth engine to google drive, however it has generated many files inside a folder.

```
// Create a geometry representing an export region.
var roi = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:15Y2IjO7bMc-COe8xOm3x1tfZdgb7GO4hK1TDWxGg');

// Load the Sentinel-2 ImageCollection.
var sentinel = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterBounds(roi);
var s2 = sentinel.filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31');
var s3 = s2.filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 0.1).sort("ascending");

// Mosaic

var mosaic = s3.median()
var bands = mosaic.select('B2', "B3", "B4", "B8")
Map.addLayer(bands,{}, "mosaic")

// Export
var task = Export.image.toDrive({
  image: bands,
  region: roi.getInfo()["coordinates"],
  scale: 10,
  description:'MOSAIC', 
  folder: 'MOSAIC', 
  fileNamePrefix: 'MOSAIC',
  maxPixels: 1e13
})
```

How to export to generate fewer files. How to download large files as mosaics to your computer?

[image: result from export]

Result from export

Comment: In my experience, you can't choose the export size. I'm surprised that it's breaking yours up into 5MB chunks, though. Mine are usually tens of MB and never exactly the same filesize.

Answer (score 6):

You do not get a valid export geometry by using `.getInfo()`. As a result it looks like Earth Engine is exporting your image globally and thus creates a multitude of subsets (called shards).

If you take the bounding box of your MultiPolygon the export produces a single file of about 11MB in size.

```js
// Export
var task = Export.image.toDrive({
  image: bands,
  region: roi.geometry().bounds(),
  description:'MOSAIC', 
  folder: 'MOSAIC', 
  fileNamePrefix: 'MOSAIC',
  maxPixels: 1e13
})
```